# Ajax output from a asp.net class

Tags: asp.net, ajax

First time I am using ajax in asp.net. But I am facing a problem.In PHP I if I echo 'add' then it works. But in asp.net class how I return or print 'add' variable?Thank you.  Below is my code

HTML :

```
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" />
  <input type="submit" id="clickButton" value="Add"/>
```

Ajax :

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $('#clickButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Class1.cs',
            data: 'input1=' + $('#input1').val() + '&input2=' + $('#input2').val(),
            success: function (reply_data) {
                $('.test').html(reply_data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
     </script>
```

Class1.cs :

```
    public int firstNumber = Request["input1"];
    public int secondNumber = Request["input2"];

    public int add = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    return add;     //problem here
```

Comment: ajax is not called as calling a *.cs file but based on the methods in the cs file and the method should marked as webMethod

Comment: Plain C# classes in ASP.NET are not exposed as web-accessible resources.  You need to make a web service, or an ASPX page, or an HTTP Handler, etc.  There are several ways to skin the cat.  Where you have `url: 'Class1.cs'`, this needs to point to a web resource.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the class in a web method in a page or something:

in your ASPX page (example Detault.aspx) :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AddNumbers( int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}
```

and then you Ajax should be like this

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('#clickButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Default.aspx/AddNumbers',
            data: {num1: $('#input1').val() , num2: $('#input2').val()},
            success: function (reply_data) {
                $('.test').html(reply_data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
     </script>
```